# Connecting PHP Script on Godaddy Hosting to Amazon RDS Not Working

Tags: php, pdo, amazon-rds

Originally, I was on a super old classic linux hosting account on Godaddy.  All the PHP scripts I had could connect to my Amazon RDS just fine.

I just upgraded my Godaddy hosting to the newest shared hosting they offer today and the PHP script doesn't seem to work anymore.

I did add the new Godaddy hosting account IP to the inbound/outbound IP list in my security group on my AWS RDS instance, but I'm getting the following error (I replaced the first portion with just hyphens):

```
Conection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '---------------.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (110)
```

My PHP script contains the following at the top:

```
define("DB_HOST", "---------------.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com");
define("DB_USER", "-------------");
define("DB_PASS", "-------------");
define("DB_NAME", "-------------");

try {
    $GLOBALS['_pdo_conn'] = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    // Set the PDO error mode to exception
    $GLOBALS['_pdo_conn']->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //echo "Connected Successfully!";   
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Conection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I also tried manually adding in the port number:

```
define("DB_HOST", "---------------.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com");
define("DB_USER", "-------------");
define("DB_PASS", "-------------");
define("DB_NAME", "-------------");

try {
    $GLOBALS['_pdo_conn'] = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";port=3306;dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    // Set the PDO error mode to exception
    $GLOBALS['_pdo_conn']->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //echo "Connected Successfully!";   
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Conection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I've checked and rechecked the IP to make sure it's correct but I can't seem to get it to connect to the Amazon RDS no matter what I try.

Is Godaddy blocking this or is there something I'm missing in the setups?

Edit:  I solved it myself (See answer response below)

Comment: Have you tried on your localhost connecting to RDS. I guess there might be problem with remote connection. please check on your local if it works then it might be problem from your hosting end.

Comment: Yes, I am hosting multiple sites on my Godaddy account.  Some are using Godaddy's databases, some are using my Amazon AWS RDS instance.  The Godaddy database connections work just fine via localhost.

Comment: You need update security groups in your RDS "DB Security Group"and add the IP of your godaddy hosting and try. Make sure that the port which you connecting 3306 is open and running.

Comment: Already did this, RamaKrishan (see 3rd paragraph of original post)

Comment: Ok. You can contact godaddy hosting, seems like they having issues connecting to RDS.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the PHP script

```html
<?php

$cURLConnection = curl_init();

curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://ifconfig.me/');
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

echo curl_exec($cURLConnection);
curl_close($cURLConnection);

?>
```

Store it in a file called whatismyip.php and place it under your public_html folder.
Access this file like,

```
http://{your-domain-name}/whatismyip.php
```

Then you can get your exact outgoing IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to **"DB Security Groups"** in the Amazon RDS settings, and allow either your EC2 instances or specific IPs (through their CIDR/IP settings) access to the DBs.

RDS by default denies access to any outside machines, including your own EC2 instance until you set up the security settings properly.

Comment: I already did this.  I have multiple hosting accounts with different hosting companies, so I'm already aware that I need to add the IPs of each hosting account to the Amazon AWS DB Security Group.

Comment: You can allow all IPs.

Comment: That is much too risky.  I don't want the entire world to have the ability to access my Amazon RDS

Comment: I see. I think that you only need to allow the IP of your host where your PHP code opens the connection. But you can try allowing all first to make sure that your problem is AWS Security related.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, DucFilan.  Setting the inbound/outbound IPs to 0.0.0.0/0 in the AWS security group does indeed resolve this issue.  Perhaps the IP showing on my Godaddy hosting is not the actual IP of the server.  It just seems so odd to me that this would be the case.  I will ask Godaddy if the IP is incorrect.

Comment: If you're going to use RDS, you should host in EC2. The latency between GoDaddy and Amazon will likely be enough to drastically impact your site's performance.

Comment: Latency isn't really that big of a deal for the sites I'm hosting, but yeah I'm aware of that.  Thanks Ducfilan ^^

Answer (score 0):

Since I had multiple hosting with multiple different companies, I was able to make a simple curl request from a php script on my Godaddy account to one of my other hosting accounts I had with a different company to see what the actual IP was from Godaddy's end making the curl request.

Turns out the IP is different from the IP Godaddy provided on the cpanel dashboard.  Not sure why this is.  My only guess is Godaddy tries to make it more difficult for less experienced customers to find this IP.

Adding this IP I found to my Amazon security group inbound/outbound list fixed this issue.